# Getting incorrect results in Qlikview Analyser

Tags: sql, select, report, qlikview

I need help with a report I am trying to create with Olikview Analyser. The problem is I keep getting incorrect results. I think it may be related to the metrics being slightly wrong. The data source definitely has the correct figures, but when I am trying to run select queries results are not right. Here is an example. To see sales for Last Week Last Year (sales for Last week 2015)

Currently the Analyser code is as follows:

```
sum({$<DATE_WEEK={$(LastWeekLY)}, DATE_FYEAR {$(LastWeekYearLY)}>}POS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS)
+
sum({$<DATE_WEEK={$(LastWeekLY)}, DATE_FYEAR {$(LastWeekYearLY)}>}CS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS)
+
sum({$<DATE_WEEK={$(LastWeekLY)}, DATE_FYEAR={$(LastWeekYearLY)}>}CO_ITEM_TOTAL)
```

However, the figures I get are far too high. Are there any obvious errors in the code?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The syntax of the expression is ok. If you are not going to use `set analysis` then `{$}` is not needed. But this expression will not give you the Last Week Last Year value unless you select Last Week Last Year.

Comment: If you replace `$(LastWeekLY)` and `$(LastWeekYearLY)` with the actual year and week values the numbers are the same? Just to eliminate issue with the variable

Comment: You are missing equal signs for DATE_FYEAR?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sum({$<DATE_WEEK={'$(LastWeekLY)'}, DATE_FYEAR={'$(LastWeekYearLY)'}>} numsum(POS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS,CS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS,CO_ITEM_TOTAL))
```

sometimes the weeks/years are stored as text and not numbers..so this will fix this issue.
If this does not work then you have a problem in your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
sum( {$< DATE_WEEK = {$(#LastWeekLY)} , DATE_FYEAR = {$(#LastWeekYearLY)} >} POS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS ))+
```

sum( {$< DATE_WEEK = {$(#LastWeekLY)} , DATE_FYEAR = {$(#LastWeekYearLY)} >} CS_SALES_VALUE_GROSS ))+
sum( {$< DATE_WEEK = {$(#LastWeekLY)} , DATE_FYEAR = {$(#LastWeekYearLY)} >} CO_ITEM_TOTAL))